# Solution to differential equation $\left( 1-\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)w(x,y,z)-g(x,y,z+h)=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:
$\left( 1-\lambda\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)w(x,y,z)-g(x,y,z+h)=0$

here $g(x,y,z+h)$ is a known function that however i will leave unspecified moreover we are dealing with Real variables and constants.

The paper that i'm following reports the following solution:
$w(x,y,z)= \frac{1}{2\lambda}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{s}{2\lambda}}g(x,y,z+h+s)ds$

I'm sure this comes from an exponential integrating factor, in fact arranging the original differential equation in the following way:
$\frac{-1}{2 \lambda}w(x,y,z)e^{-\frac{z}{2 \lambda}}+e^{-\frac{z}{2 \lambda}}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}w(x,y,z)=-\frac{1}{2 \lambda}e^{-\frac{z}{2 \lambda}}g(x,y,z+h)$

we obtain the following differential equation:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left( e^{-\frac{z}{2 \lambda}}w(x,y,z)\right)=-\frac{1}{2 \lambda}e^{-\frac{z}{2 \lambda}}g(x,y,z+h)$

now i'm quite clueless on how to proceed, any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you cite the paper? At present, the factor of two seems altogether mysterious.

Comment: the paper is "Brownian motion near a partial-slip boundary:A local probe of the no-slip condition" by T.M. Squires and E. Lauga published on Physics of Fluids (2005) .In particular i'm refering to the steps required to obtain equation B11 starting from Equation B7; note that in this question I simplified the problem with respect to equation B7 that contains an additional term in the differential equation (that is $2\lambda w^{\perp}(r,\lambda)$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we may note that the $x,y$ dependence is irrelevant, along with the shift in the argument of $g(x,y,z)$. To that end I'll introduce $W(z)=w(x,y,z)$ and $G(z)=g(x,y,z+h)\to g(z)$. Then we just have a simplified ODE given as $(1-\lambda D_z)W(z)=G(z)$.

This can indeed be handled by an integrating factor by observing

$$\dfrac{d}{dz}\left(e^{-z/\lambda}W\right)=-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-z/\lambda}\left(W-\lambda \frac{dW}{dz}\right)=-\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-z/\lambda}G(z),$$ which if integrated on the interval $[z,\infty)$ implies

$$e^{-z/\lambda}W(z)-(e^{-z/\lambda}W)_{z=\infty}=\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{z}^\infty e^{-z'/\lambda}G(z')\,dz'$$

We can drop the boundary term at $z=\infty$ on the LHS if we assume that $W(z)$ does not grow exponentially fast as $z\to\infty$. Shifting the exponential prefactor to the RHS then gives

$$W(z)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{z}^\infty e^{-(z'-z)/\lambda}G(z')\,dz'
=\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-s/\lambda}G(z+s)\,ds$$

where $s:=z'-z$. Returning to the original $(x,y,z)$ dependence yields the integral representation

$$w(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-s/\lambda}g(x,y,z+h+s)\,ds.$$ This is very close to the desired form; what remains mysterious are the factors of two. This may explained by going back to the paper cited in the comments to the OP: Those equations are defined with the operator $1-2\lambda \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}$. Consequently we should make the replacement $\lambda\mapsto 2\lambda$ in the results above when comparing with the formulae found in the paper, yielding the result in the OP.

Comment: the factor of  two comes from a mistake in reporting the differential equation, that actually is: $\left( 1-2\lambda \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \right) w(x,y,z)-g(x,y,z+h)=0$